# addOperation to add two identical operation to a queue, but only one operation is running

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a task which need to add operation to a queue and run it in sequence.

but when use addOperation to add two identical operation to a queue, but only one operation is running.

the queue is init as follows:

`_lineItemsToPrintQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
_lineItemsToPrintQueue.name = @"com.bindo.lineItemsToPrint";
_lineItemsToPrintQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
_lineItemsToPrintQueue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUtility;`

Comment: How do you define and add the operations?

Comment: `BPLineItemPrintOperation *lineItemPrintOperation = [[BPLineItemPrintOperation alloc] initWithKitchenSlip:slip];[self.kitchenLineItemsToPrint.lineItemsToPrintQueue addOperation:lineItemPrintOperation];`

Comment: after google, I find someone says that 'NSOperationQueue refuses to re-queue the SAME NSOperation object.', and I have overwrite the isEqual: function to always return NO, but seems still not work.

Comment: @DamonYuan Hi. Do you create a two identical operations `op1` `op2` (and will call the `addOpearation` for each) or one operation `op1` (and will call the `addOperation` twice)?